# How can I setup 2 different containers to run on 2 different DNS names in Kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, dns, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

So I've got my backend and front-end as seperate containers in the one **Kubernetes Deployment**.

At the moment I'm having to access the front-end & backend via different **ports**.

E.g `example.com:5000 = frontend` & `example.com:7000 = backend`

I'm wondering how I can setup my front-end container to run on `www.example.com` & my backend container to run on `api.example.com`

I'm using gcp (google cloud), have setup my dns properly & am having to access the services (web apps) using the ports I assigned to each of them (5000=frontend,7000=backend).

I'm thinking of a possible solution which is manual, but am wondering whether there is something built into **Kubernetes**. This solution would be:

I'd setup an nginx container in my Kubernetes cluster that would run on port 80, so any request that comes through would be redirected to the appropriate ports:

E.g I could have `api.example.com point to <my_cluster_ip>/backend` & the same for my front-end `<my_cluster_ip>/frontend` and let nginx point /backend to **port 5000** and /frontend to **port 7000**

I'm hoping there is something built into kubernetes that I can use? Here is my deployment config as it stands:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "my_container"
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "my_app"
        }        
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "backend",
            "image": "backend_url",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 7000
              }
            ],
            "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "NODE_PORT",
                "value": "7000"
              },
              {
                "name": "NODE_ENV",
                "value": "production"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "frontend",
            "image": "frontend_url",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 5000
              }
            ],
            "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "PORT",
                "value": "5000"
              },
              {
                "name": "NODE_ENV",
                "value": "production"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters, you should not base exposing your service on Deployment. To do that, you should cover your Deployment(s) with Service(s). Read up on http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/ for that.

When you go through the lecture, you might notice that it is perfectly possible to set two services that match the same backing pods (Endpoints) but on different port (ie. front:80->5000 api:80->7000). The problem is, that it still is exposing your work only inside the k8s cluster. To publish it externally you can use Service of type NodePort or LoadBalancer (first one has the disadvantage of using high ports to expose your services to the public, second one will be a separate LB (hence IP) per service).

What I personally prefer to publicly expose services is using Ingress/IngressController http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/

Finally, when you split your solution with two services (front/api) you will see that there is no real reason to keep them together in one deployment/pod. If you separate them as two distinct deployments, you will get a more flexible architecture, and more fine grained control over your solution.

Comment: Yeah I like this solution better than my current one. I was initially going to do it this way but I wanted to take baby steps as I was just starting out with kubernetes!

Comment: 1 question: Say if you had a backend & front-end in two different services, would you call the backend via the `cluster ip` (wouldn't this be quicker as they're local?) or the `hostname` (e.g `api.example.com`)?

Comment: you can call it by cluster IP, but that requires some discovery, which in case of kubernetes is provided out of the box by kube-dns. So in fact you should connect by DNS. If you run both deployments/services in the same namespace it is enough to call service by its name like `backend` or by its FQDN like `backend.default.svc.cluster.local` (if you're in `default` namespace). These domain names will resolve to the ClusterIP - the same for the most of time, but it can change if you explicitly remove and recreate the service.

Comment: 1 more question! I ended up implementing an ingress controller. Does the ingress controller automatically setup DNS record sets?! Because at the moment I'd have to setup record sets and point the record set (e.g `api.example.com`) to my cluster IP (e.g `10.1.1.1`). I'm a bit confused to whether the ingress controller does this for me?

Comment: No, ingress controller it self has no DNS integration. As ingress is intended mostly for use with external traffic. Thus normally you should expose your IngressController via ie. cloud loadbalancer (possibly via service of LoadBalancer type). Then you are in charge of setting your DNS entries. I myself use wildcard domain records for internal things like *.ing.mydomain.tld pointing to IngressControllers LB IP, thus I don't need to adapt it each time I want to expose some new subdomain

Answer (score 1):

Using nginx to route requests to k8s IP addresses is unnecessary. In order to make it work you need to have the pods DNS name which includes  its IP address. If you scale that pod, you need to modify the nginx config each time with the new hostname/DNS name. If your pods get killed, there is no guarantee, they`ll get the same IPs after restart. So basically, not a good approach.

Probably a better design is to separate the front end from the back end. This way you can deploy them independently. The back end will probably be more resource hungry and when you scale it, you do not need to carry the front end along and share resources with it.

If you choose to separate your services, check out [k8s services](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/). They are easy to understand and fast to set up. After you create a k8s service for front end and back end, you can get DNS name resolving to the name you gave your service automatically(and use it in your code of course).

Since you are using gke, you can expose those services(or only the frontend) to the world via a loadbalancer by using [k8s ingress](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/)